# rails paperclip url wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Everything is fine, except URL of image it adds GET request to the of link

```
"/system/users/images/000/000/074/original/e742caf8bdfb1536e39060eb9d10a4ab.jpeg**?2015**"
```

Because of this, image is not available(even I open it by direct link), if I delete ?2015, everything works good. Why gem is adding to the end of link get request?

I used default :path, :url(in public/system folder)
and this one

```
:path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension" 
:url => "/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

The problem is in both of ways((

Comment: Could you please provide code, that generates link and the Image model?

Comment: @arthur.karganyan, sorry that didn't do it befote. Can you check plz

Comment: What is wrong with my question, why -3?((

Comment: I didn't downvote you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `:use_timestamp => false` to your paperclip configuration.